# Multiple foreign keys in same table

Tags: mysql

Can I reference 3 foreign keys in MYSQL? because in INNODB, only one foreign key constraint appears in the relational view.

Comment: Have you tried to? What is the syntax you'd like to work?

Comment: I had to do `echo "MULTIPLE FOREIGN KEYS IN SAME TABLE" | tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]'`...

Comment: What if when I am using composite foreign keys. Is this possible?

CREATE TABLE table
(
patient_id int,
hperson_id int,
hfhudcode_id int,
diagnosis_id int,
primary key (patient_id, hperson_id,hfhudcode_id,diagnosis_id),
foreign key (patient_id, hperson_id,hfhudcode_id) references table1 (patient_id,hperson_id,hfhudcode_id),
)

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Yes you can do,

**EXAMPLE:**

```
CREATE TABLE table
(
user_id int,
track_id int,
primary key (user_id, track_id),
foreign key (user_id) references table1(table1Column),
foreign key(track_id) references table2(table2Column)
)
```

Composite Primary Key;

```
FOREIGN KEY ('column1','column2','column3') 
REFERENCES table1('column1','column2','column3') ;
```

Comment: @Atalie i updated my code for composite foriegn keys.see once