# Foreign keys from two different tables

Tags: mysql

I want to associate two foreign keys (city_id and country_id) in one table to two primary keys, each one of them in a different table. Is this the right syntax?

```
FOREIGN KEY (city_id) REFERENCES cities(id),
FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES countries(id)
```

Comment: Yes, that's the right syntax. Did you try it? As long as the other 2 tables have indexes on the referenced columns it should be fine (I assume they are probably auto-increment ids, as primary key, so that fulfills the requirement)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699045/multiple-foreign-keys-in-same-table)